# How to show the Tabbar in the About page

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using the Xamarin.Form Shell

Link Sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout

Please help me. How to show the Tabbar in the About page?

The source code of AppShell.xaml

```
<FlyoutItem Route="animals"
                Title="Animals"
                FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
      <ShellContent Route="bears"
                      Style="{StaticResource BearsShell}"
                      Title="Bears"
                      Icon="bear.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:BearsPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
    <ShellContent Route="about"
                  Style="{StaticResource AboutShell}"
                  Title="About"
                  Icon="info.png"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:AboutPage}" />
```

...

[image]

Comment: Hi , you can put the `about` page inside the same `FlyoutItem` with the front pages , then it will show in tabbar .

Comment: If put the about page inside the same FlyoutItem, The tabbar will show about tab but I want to have 4 elements in the tabbar only then how?

Comment: Okey , I have tried in local site . It seems can not achieve that in Shell Applicaltion.